# Not Found: /menu.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got an error

> Not Found: /menu.js.

I wanna embed jQuery into HTML,app(child app) is in testapp(parent app),and app has index.html&menu.js. index.html&menu.js is in templates folder which is in app.

**index.html**

```
<html>
　<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./menu.js" ></script>
  <body>
    <div class="list-company_demand">
      <ul class="menu demand-parent">
        <li>
          <a class="menu-item">A（a）</a>
          <ul class="menu-child">
            <li>
              <a class="menu-item">1</a>
              <a class="menu-item">2</a>
              <a class="menu-item">3</a>
              <a class="menu-item">4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="menu-item">A（b）</a>
          <ul class="menu-child">
            <li>
              <a class="menu-item">1</a>
              <a class="menu-item">2</a>
              <a class="menu-item">3</a>
              <a class="menu-item">4</a>
              <a class="menu-item">5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="menu-item">A（c）</a>
          <ul class="menu-child">
            <li>
              <a class="menu-item">1</a>
              <a class="menu-item">2</a>
              <a class="menu-item">3</a>
              <a class="menu-item">4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="menu-item">A（d）</a>
          <ul class="menu-child">
            <li>
              <a class="menu-item">1</a>
              <a class="menu-item">2</a>
              <a class="menu-item">3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**menu.js**

```
   $(function() {
      $('.menu-item').on('click', function() {
        var child = $(this).next('.menu-child');
        $('.list-menu').height(child.height());
        child.addClass('is-active');
      });

      $('.menu-child').prepend('<li class="menu-back"><a>１つ戻る<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a></li>');

      $('.menu-back').on('click', function() {
        var parents = $(this).parent();
        parents.removeClass('is-active');
        $('.list-menu').height(parents.parent().parent().height());
      });
    });
```

I rewrote in this part into   into   but same error happens.What is wrong in my code?Am I wrong to use jQuery?How can I fix this?

By the way, by using Google validation, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) menu.js error happens in Console.
Folder structure is

testapp (app name)
-app (child app)
 -templates
   -menu.js &index.html
menu.js &index.html is in same folder templates.

Comment: your `menu.js` path is incorrect

Comment: just use menu.js. is both file in same directory?

Comment: @PankajMakwana Oh really?I cannot find the point.Which part is wrong?

Comment: @HarshPatel I put menu.js & index.html same folder(templates),is it wrong?

Comment: remove "./" from "./menu.js"

Comment: suggest you write a full html file contains head and body

Comment: @HarshPatel I remove "./" from "./menu.js" but same error happens.

Comment: @JiangangXiong  updated my full html.

Comment: the path is wrong. Check it again

Comment: @orvi I think so...but I cannot find where is wrong.If u find it, please tell me

Comment: can you tell us your folder structure ? tell me where your `index.html` and `menu.js` file locate ?

Comment: @orvi I updated my question, if u know something please help me

Comment: Try to use it as `<script src="~/templates/menu.js" ></script>`

Comment: if your index.html and menu.js in same folder put it this way `menu.js` not `./menu.js` and of course add `<head></head>` tage before starting `<body>`

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery file makes the error, replace it width `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js`, have a look:

```js
$(function() {
      $('.menu-item').on('click', function() {
        var child = $(this).next('.menu-child');
        $('.list-menu').height(child.height());
        child.addClass('is-active');
      });

      $('.menu-child').prepend('<li class="menu-back"><a>１つ戻る<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a></li>');

      $('.menu-back').on('click', function() {
        var parents = $(this).parent();
        parents.removeClass('is-active');
        $('.list-menu').height(parents.parent().parent().height());
      });
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./menu.js" ></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="list-company_demand">
      <ul class="menu demand-parent">
        <li>
          <a class="menu-item">A（a）</a>
          <ul class="menu-child">
            <li>
              <a class="menu-item">1</a>
              <a class="menu-item">2</a>
              <a class="menu-item">3</a>
              <a class="menu-item">4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="menu-item">A（b）</a>
          <ul class="menu-child">
            <li>
              <a class="menu-item">1</a>
              <a class="menu-item">2</a>
              <a class="menu-item">3</a>
              <a class="menu-item">4</a>
              <a class="menu-item">5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="menu-item">A（c）</a>
          <ul class="menu-child">
            <li>
              <a class="menu-item">1</a>
              <a class="menu-item">2</a>
              <a class="menu-item">3</a>
              <a class="menu-item">4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="menu-item">A（d）</a>
          <ul class="menu-child">
            <li>
              <a class="menu-item">1</a>
              <a class="menu-item">2</a>
              <a class="menu-item">3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thx ur comments.I wrote ur codes, but same error happens.What is wrong in my code?